# How to save some data permanently in application without using core-data or writing plistfile

Tags: objective-c

Hope all of you'll be fine.
I am building an application in which i want to synchronize my application at first-time-run with database. I mean When user will start it first time it will prompt to synchronize application with database. How can i preserve its state that the application is running first time or not.
I have done this task by writing plist file but i think it is not the proper way. I am new to IOS, someone advised me to use core-data. I have consulted tutorials on net to understand core-data but it is difficult for me, so i can not use core data for the said purpose.
Someone also asked me to use cache files, but it also not seems the proper way. I think cache files can be deleted accidentally or by some other mean.
 Is there any other way to save just one boolean value (applicationRunFirstTime yes/no). Need your valueable advise and ideas. Many Thanks.

Comment: Use `NSUserDefaults`

Comment: Thank you ShahiM for your such a quick response. Let me try your suggestion.